# Cannot create InnoDB tables

Tags: percona

I have a working Percona database server running multiple databases with mostly InnoDB tables (maybe a few hundred tables total).  Any table that exists is working fine, yet I cannot convert any existing MyISAM tables or even create new InnoDB tables in any schema (even new fresh ones).

In fact I can trigger the crash (`Error Code: 2013. Lost conenction  to MySQL server during query`) as minimally as this:

```
create schema testschema;
use testschema;
create table testtable (
    testfield int(10)
);
```

(InnoDB is the default engine, and I get the same result making the engine explicit, while specifying MyISAM creates the table successfully.

What gives?

Some diagnostics:

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep mysqld$)/limits
...
Max open files            8192                 8192                 files
...
```

Starting from the crash, (large) error log has these possibly notable lines

```
2016-12-19 19:06:43 7f3880047700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139880642672384 in file fsp0fsp.cc line 1899
...
23:06:43 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
...
stack_bottom = 7f3880046ea0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0x8f4b9b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x378)[0x647468]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f388cf34390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f388c2d8428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f388c2da02a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x55f90b]
...
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9bfcd4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15ha_create_tableP3THDPKcS2_S2_P24st_ha_create_informationbb+0x1fe)[0x58b9be]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16rea_create_tableP3THDPKcS2_S2_P24st_ha_create_informationR4ListI12Create_fieldEjP6st_keyP7handlerb+0x1d3)[0x771033]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x72bb5e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z26mysql_create_table_no_lockP3THDPKcS2_P24st_ha_create_informationP10Alter_infojPb+0x114)[0x72c734]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18mysql_create_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP24st_ha_create_informationP10Alter_info+0xdf)[0x72c98f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x5696)[0x6d9596]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x604)[0x6daa64]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x19c2)[0x6dc542]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x245)[0x6a0bf5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x39)[0x6a0c49]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x140)[0x98da00]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f388cf2a6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f388c3a982d]
...
Query (7f3804004c10): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 76
Status: NOT_KILLED
...
161219 19:06:43 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
161219 19:06:43 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
```

A restart occurs which performs rollback and ens successfully, though the log does mention this `InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 18814, file name /storage/logs/mysql/mysql-bin.000005` and there is no binlog set up (this path no longer exists either).

```
ignore_builtin_innodb......................... OFF
innodb_adaptive_flushing...................... ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm.................. 10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index.................... ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions......... 1
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay............... 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size............... 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval................. 5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock.................... OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog...................... OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl......................... OFF
innodb_api_trx_level.......................... 0
innodb_autoextend_increment................... 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode...................... 1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown........... OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now................... OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename................... ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances.................. 8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort................. OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup............ OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now................... OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_populate................... OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size....................... 805306368
innodb_change_buffer_max_size................. 25
innodb_change_buffering....................... all
innodb_checksum_algorithm..................... innodb
innodb_checksums.............................. ON
innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor................. high_checkpoint
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled.................. OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency..................... 0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct...... 5
innodb_compression_level...................... 6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max................ 50
innodb_concurrency_tickets.................... 5000
innodb_corrupt_table_action................... assert
innodb_data_file_path......................... ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir.......................... 
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache................ OFF
innodb_doublewrite............................ ON
innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm.............. backoff
innodb_fake_changes........................... OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown.......................... 1
innodb_file_format............................ Antelope
innodb_file_format_check...................... ON
innodb_file_format_max........................ Antelope
innodb_file_per_table......................... ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout................... 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit................ 1
innodb_flush_method........................... 
innodb_flush_neighbors........................ 1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops..................... 30
innodb_force_load_corrupted................... OFF
innodb_force_recovery......................... 0
innodb_foreground_preflush.................... exponential_backoff
innodb_ft_aux_table........................... 
innodb_ft_cache_size.......................... 8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print................... OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword..................... ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size...................... 84
innodb_ft_min_token_size...................... 3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize................... 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit.................. 2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table............... 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree..................... 2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size.................... 640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table................. 
innodb_io_capacity............................ 200
innodb_io_capacity_max........................ 2000
innodb_kill_idle_transaction.................. 0
innodb_large_prefix........................... OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout...................... 50
innodb_locking_fake_changes................... ON
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog................ OFF
innodb_log_arch_dir........................... ./
innodb_log_arch_expire_sec.................... 0
innodb_log_archive............................ OFF
innodb_log_block_size......................... 512
innodb_log_buffer_size........................ 8388608
innodb_log_checksum_algorithm................. innodb
innodb_log_compressed_pages................... ON
innodb_log_file_size.......................... 50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group..................... 2
innodb_log_group_home_dir..................... ./
innodb_lru_scan_depth......................... 1024
innodb_max_bitmap_file_size................... 104857600
innodb_max_changed_pages...................... 1000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct.................... 75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm................ 0
innodb_max_purge_lag.......................... 0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay.................... 0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups.................... 1
innodb_monitor_disable........................ 
innodb_monitor_enable......................... 
innodb_monitor_reset.......................... 
innodb_monitor_reset_all...................... 
innodb_old_blocks_pct......................... 37
innodb_old_blocks_time........................ 1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size.............. 134217728
innodb_open_files............................. 512
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only................. OFF
innodb_page_size.............................. 16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks.................... OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size....................... 300
innodb_purge_threads.......................... 1
innodb_random_read_ahead...................... OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold................... 56
innodb_read_io_threads........................ 4
innodb_read_only.............................. OFF
innodb_replication_delay...................... 0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout.................... OFF
innodb_rollback_segments...................... 128
innodb_sched_priority_cleaner................. 19
innodb_show_locks_held........................ 10
innodb_show_verbose_locks..................... 0
innodb_sort_buffer_size....................... 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay........................ 6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc...................... ON
innodb_stats_method........................... nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata...................... OFF
innodb_stats_persistent....................... ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages.......... 20
innodb_stats_sample_pages..................... 8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages........... 8
innodb_status_output.......................... OFF
innodb_status_output_locks.................... OFF
innodb_strict_mode............................ OFF
innodb_support_xa............................. ON
innodb_sync_array_size........................ 1
innodb_sync_spin_loops........................ 30
innodb_table_locks............................ ON
innodb_thread_concurrency..................... 0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay..................... 10000
innodb_track_changed_pages.................... OFF
innodb_undo_directory......................... .
innodb_undo_logs.............................. 128
innodb_undo_tablespaces....................... 0
innodb_use_atomic_writes...................... OFF
innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit..... ON
innodb_use_native_aio......................... ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc......................... ON
innodb_version................................ 5.6.22-71.0
innodb_write_io_threads....................... 4
```

Comment: Check that the Percona binaries themselves are not corrupted. If they are OK, then you have either found a bug in Percona or have defective hardware.

Comment: When I've seen similar errors in the past it's usually involved people manually copying .ibd files around like they did with .MYI and .MYD tables.  You can't do that.  If that's the case, your innodb data dictionary is likely corrupted.  The easiest (IMO) fix (and the one with the highest probability of solving the problem) is to dump all the data in your innodb tables, shut down the server, physically delete all InnoDB DB files (including ibdata1) and recreate them.  ALL of them on the server.  This lives in ibdata1 for all the tables, even if the tables are using file_per_table.

Comment: Hmm...I wasn't copying around .ibd files but I was converting multiple MyISAM tables when it started.  I have a third option which is to do a zfs rollback to a snapshot I made before the conversion while mysql was not running, and repeat the process in smaller steps with more snapshots between..  I've been thinking that wasn't likely the problem because mysqlrepair reports no issues.  Bloody ibdata1 - it needs to DIAF already.  It's just not reasonable to have such a fragile single point of failure.

Comment: No dice.  But since the dump included system tables (plugins, users, etc.), it wasn't that big a deal to just rebuild.